# Multiple selection with multiple this

Tags: javascript, jquery

need help on Jquery multiple selection.

Here is the code

```
$.each(($("#reciprocitationAgreement option:selected:not([disabled]), #reciprocitationAgreement input")), function() {
     $(this).text();
});
```

There are 2 types of element that passes trought each loop.
1 - Select (option) - get **text** from option element
2 - Input field - get **value** from input fields

There are 2 selected elements.
Is there any way to point in the same block of code to `$(this, option).text();` and `$(this, input).val()`?

Comment: hum... if you wan't to do 2 completely differents things, I don't think its a bad idea to split your selectors in 2 different ones

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy, you can do it inside the same function, you don't need two functions. Just check if the `tagName` of the element is `INPUT` and then behave accordingly:

```
$.each(($("#reciprocitationAgreement option:selected:not([disabled]), #reciprocitationAgreement input")), function() {
     if (this.tagName == 'INPUT') {
         $(this).val(); // ...
     } else {
         $(this).text(); // ...
     }  
 });
```

Comment: What do you mean by TagName?

Comment: The tag name is the name of the tag of an html element, like "DIV" or "A" or "SPAN" etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  var data = [];
    $.each([ $("#reciprocitationAgreement option:selected:not([disabled])").text(), $("#reciprocitationAgreement input").val() ], function(k, v) {
       data.push(v);
      // do stuff with `data` , and / or ,
      // do stuff with `v`
      console.log(data);
      $("body").append(v);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/77jLN/

Answer (score 0):

Move your code inside function at find 2 types of input

```
 $.each(($("#reciprocitationAgreement option:selected:not([disabled])")), function() {
         doSomething($(this).text())
     });

 $.each(($("#reciprocitationAgreement input")), function() {
         doSomething($(this).val())
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a JQuery extension method that will allow you to scale this in the future if you decide to add different types.  It also has the advantage of being used in many places and can be called with just one line by saying `$("selectorgoeshere").getValue()`.

```
$.fn.getValue = function () {
    var returnValue = "";
    switch ($(this)[0].nodeName) {
        case "INPUT":
            returnValue = $(this).val();
            break;
        case "OPTION":
            returnValue = $(this).text();
            break;
        default:
            returnValue = $(this)[0];
            break;
    } // end switch
    return returnValue;
};
$(function () {
    $("#clickMe").click(function (e) {
        $("#reciprocitationAgreement option:selected:not([disabled]), #reciprocitationAgreement input").each(function () {
            console.log($(this).getValue());
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/Z89vW/